# Has anyone tried to delpoy Ruby on Rails application on servage.net?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ftp

I have bought http://www.servage.net/ hosting and in their Features page there is RoR support listed [http://www.servage.net/web-hosting/features/action:web_features/](http://www.servage.net/web-hosting/features/action%3aweb_features/). 
I tried to do things as it's written here https://secure.servage.net/wiki/Install_Ruby_on_Rails_application but with no luck. I also opened ticket in support, but they couldn't help me.

So I wonder, if anyone has done this before, please help me!

Comment: Those instructions are for using fastcgi. Rails stopped generating the supporting files for fastcgi automatically several years ago, although since rack supports fgci it should in theory work. It does however suggest that the company has little rails expertise.

Comment: Thanks Frederick, for you answer, but I guess I'll switch to Cloud hosting for Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Lado, my experience with hosting is that you have 3 types of company:

> 1. 90's "Get You Online" company
> 2. 00's "Wordpress" shared hosting
> 3. 10's "Cloud" hosting

Rails works best on the 2010's 'cloud' hosting. The reason is because you get complete control over your own environment, ensuring you can support & install all the dependencies you need

You get a lot of companies trying to support dependency-rich applications with their shared hosting infrastructure. The problem is they will never be able to support your app in the most efficient way -- always behind with updates & their servers will mainly be designed to provide "shared" hosting to their clients

I'd personally recommend using `Heroku` (as this interfaces with Amazon's cloud), or [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud). Don't try and use Rails with a shared hosting provider - it's more pain than it's worth

Comment: Yes, deploying on Heroku, is much easier than on any other hosting providers I suppose. I was just wondering if I could publish it on my shared hosting too.
Well I guess in Rails application cases I have to use Cloud hosting.

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: You *can* use other shared hosting, but the point is they are not designed for it. Cloud hosting providers like Amazon, RackSpace, Heroku etc, are designed to help scale & support your apps -- means low latency & lots of dependnecies

Comment: @Rick and what about VPS? Would you recommend to deploy rails app on VPS server?

Comment: Sure! "Cloud" hosting is just a type of VPS (it's deployed over a whole fleet of servers rather than just a single server). VPS is fine, but you'll struggle to scale it

Comment: What do you by saying "scale"?

Comment: If you start getting 100's of users per day - how can you allocate more memory to a VPS which is sharing resources on a single box? Cloud deployment makes computing power "elastic" (hence why Amazon call it Elastic Computing Cloud / EC2). Cloud gives you a slider to add more memory, VPS gives you the option to upgrade